# LOV data is not updating while entering row in table in adf 12c

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have created a SQL Query based List Of Value (LOV) and attach with view object of some table.
When i build my project it shows data from table in LOV successfully.
But when i update my table in database (from where LOV is getting data), LOV is not showing updated data untill/unless i rebuild my project.

I have tried to resolve it by autorefresh="true" in LOV view object, but it show error of null pointer exception after building my project. Here is code and screenshot of error:

In LOV view object i have written AutoRefresh="true":

```
<ViewObject
  xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bc4j"
  Name="Program_Name_LOV"
  Version="12.2.1.9.14"
  InheritPersonalization="merge"
  BindingStyle="OracleName"
  CustomQuery="true"
  RowClass="model.lov.Program_Name_LOVRowImpl"
  ComponentClass="model.lov.Program_Name_LOVImpl"
  PageIterMode="Full"
  AutoRefresh="true">
```

After building my project, I got this error:

[image: error after building my project]

After removing AutoRefresh="true" in LOV view object, there is no error showing after building my project.

I am using jdeveloper 12c with 12c database.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that your view object always query the latest data in your database do the following :

- Go to your List Of Value's View Object
- If not already, Open the Property Inspector panel (Jdev top menu > View > Property Inspector)
- In the Property Inspector change the value of Tuning > Auto Refresh from  **false** to **True**

Comment: I have already tried this, but after doing this and running my project it gives error of null pointer exception.

Comment: i have updated my question, can you please help regarding this